# postgres flutter db connection won't open

Tags: database, postgresql, flutter, dart

im trying to connect a postgresdb to flutter

```
import 'package:cadastro/screens/register_form_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';

final _connection = PostgreSQLConnection('localhost', 5432, 'darttest',
    username: 'postgres', password: 'randompassword');

databaseConnection() async {
  await _connection.open().then((value) {
    debugPrint("Database Connected!");
  });
}

void main() async {
  if (_connection.isClosed) {
    await databaseConnection();
  }
  _connection.transaction((ctx) async {
    var result = await ctx.query("SELECT * FROM users");
    print(result);
    await ctx.query(
        "insert into users values (2 ,'bbb', 'gui', 'segurança', '12345', 'grupo1')");
  });
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

error message on await _connection.open():
SocketException (SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 56836)

things i already tried:

1. I modified pg_hba.conf on host part i changed to 0.0.0.0/0
2. Tried my computer ip adress and 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost
3. Altered user postgres password
4. Tried on node server and it connected
5. Tried both on emulator and personal cellphone
6. I've tried enabling isUnix in postgressconnection(error changed "no such file or directory", errno = 2)